# mysql auto increment a character AA999 to AB001 with mysql

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to auto increment a character AA999 to AB001 with mysql?

table:test

ID   Name ---->  ID   NameId
1    Arun        15   AA999
2    Ram         30   AB001

Comment: You can not increment a character

Comment: Auto increment field should be Integer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL AutoIncrement character field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16762132/mysql-autoincrement-character-field)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. You need an `int` field to achieve this with `auto_increment` modifier and a stored function which can convert it into hexa `varchar` for representation. So, you cannot do this with a stored `varchar`-ish type, but you can do it with an `int`. If you really want to skip **AB000**, then it is more difficult, which involves the creation of a row just for this support, which seems too hacky for me.

Comment: if you wouldn't mind, can yo supply me with a sample MySQL query to make that happen